# Built In Method in Typescript to Find Class inside a Tag Name or a Sibling of a Class

Tags: html, typescript

Here's the sample html:

```
<div aria-atomic="true" aria-live="polite" class="sr-only">
</div>

<sl-render ng-reflect-image-url="xxx">

    <div class="imageBackground" tabindex="0">
        <button class="OpenButton" tabindex="0">Open</button>
    </div>

    <div aria-atomic="true" aria-live="polite" class="sr-only">
    </div>

</sl-render>
```

As you can see, there are multiple `sr-only` element in the example, but I only want the `sr-only` that's inside `sl-render` tag. Here's a not-so-clean solution:

1. query `document.getElementsByTagName('sl-render')`
2. based on 1, query another `document.getElementsByClassName('.sr-only')` since `sr-only` is inside `sl-render` tag

I am looking for a cleaner solution than the above, perhaps a built-in function to find `sr-only` class that is below `imageBackground` class?

Comment: why not `document.querySelector`?

Comment: @DanielA.White sry i forgot to mention, there are multiple sr-only in the html and i only want the one that is inside the sl-render. I have updated the question to clarify

Comment: with `querySelector` you can pass css selectors to express exactly what you need

Comment: `document.querySelector('sl-render > .srt-only')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `querySelector` or `querySelectorAll` with the selector `sl-render > div.sr-only`.

  - `sl-render > div.sr-only` will select all `<div class="sr-only">` which is an immediate child of any `<sl-render>` elements.
- TypeScript doesn't (yet) support type-safe results of `querySelector` but this is one of situations where using `as` is fine:

  - `querySelector`'s return-type should be refined to `HTMLElement | null` or a subtype there-of (e.g. `HTMLDivElement | null`.
  - `querySelectorAll`'s return-type should be refined to `NodeListOf<HTMLElement>` (there is no need for the type-union with `| null` as it's a collection-type).

Like so:

```js
const srOnlyDivsInSLRenderElements = document.querySelectorAll( 'sl-render > div.sr-only' ) as NodeListOf<HTMLDivElement>;

for( const div of srOnlyDivsInSLRenderElements ) {
    console.log( div.outerHTML );
}
```